# How to disable a button from the component in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can i disable the button present in the template from the components properties? suppose i have a component like this

```
    export class PolicyAddComponent {
      ToggleButton: boolean = true;

      SubmitPolicy(value: any) {
        ToggleButton = false;
      }
    }
```

and i have a template like this

```
 <form role="form" [formGroup]="PolicyForm" (ngSubmit)="SubmitPolicy(PolicyForm.value)">
   <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="RateDate" placeholder="Rate Date">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ShowIssuedPolicy()">Show Issue policy</button>
 </form>
```

I want the submit button to be disabled and the Show Issue policy button to be enabled once the submit button is clicked. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that using the following:

Component

```js
export class PolicyAddComponent{
    ToggleButton: boolean = true;
    SubmitPolicy(value: any) {
        ToggleButton=false;
    }
}
```

Template

```html
<form role="form" [formGroup]="PolicyForm" (ngSubmit)="SubmitPolicy(PolicyForm.value)">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="RateDate" placeholder="Rate Date">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="SubmitPolicy()">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ShowIssuedPolicy()" [disabled]="ToggleButton">Show Issue policy</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways how to achieve it is to implement a `boolean` variable, which will hold a `true` value **until** the user has clicked and seen the `Issue policy`. Then, the variable sets into `false` and the submit button is enabled.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]='checkPolicy'>Submit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="ShowIssuedPolicy()">Show Issue policy</button>


checkPolicy: boolean = true;

ShowIssuedPolicy(){
  this.checkPolicy = false;
}
```

**[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/TshR44NB7OqHSPT5t5wx?p=preview)**